# Two 3 way switches, only one works

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

I have 3 way switches at the top and bottom of the stairs operating two cans in the ceiling.  For 20 years, they've never worked right.  Either switch would turn the lights on or off, like a single pole switch, but neither would turn the lights off if the other switch had turned them on. In other words, flipping either switch up would turn the lights on, but both had to be down to turn them off. That's the history.  Now I find the bottom switch does nothing at all, while the upper switch will turn the lights on and off. I disconnected both switches and tested the wires in each box for voltage.  Both switch boxes have one romex bundle going into the box, BWRGnd, and nothing else.  In both boxes I found 120 volts on the white wire when testing it to ground.  No voltage on the other colors.  I went ahead and replaced the lower switch, thinking it may have gone bad.  I wired the white to the common terminal in both boxes, and the black and red to the travelers.  Still, the upper switch works, the lower one does nothing.  I've spent many hours scouring the internet for this problem and found nothing quite like it.  Can someone advise me?

[image]

[image]

Comment: When you're measuring voltage to ground, are the wires attached to the switches?

Comment: The original setup sounds like an open traveler problem -- the new symptoms *are* unusual though, and may be a sign that the bottom switch has been shorted/bypassed...I would seriously distrust the existing wiring in this case.  Do you know if the incoming power is at the fixture or one of the switches?

Comment: No, when measuring voltage, the switches were detached.  I expected to find voltage on one wire in one box.  Was surprised to find it in both boxes.  Wiring is above sheetrock in vaulted ceiling, no attic, so the only way to look at it would be to remove the cans.  I'm assuming power is at one of the cans, but don't know that for certain.  I've moved wires around on the lower switch and got it to work, but then the upper switch would not turn lights off.  Don't remember now what combination that was, but it had to have the white with 120 volts on it on one of the travelers.

Comment: It sounds like you are describing the same condition you started with.   Both switches have to be OFF for the light to be OFF, otherwise the lights are always ON.  Yes?

Comment: Chris, at the moment the upper switch toggles the lights on and off.  The bottom switch does nothing.  I have the white wire on the common terminal on both switches and the red and black on the traveler terminals.  The white has 120 volts in both boxes when checked to ground, with no switch attached.

Comment: I've probably confused the issue by describing the condition before the lower switch quit working.  But what you described, Chris, is what I had back then.  This is in a house I lived in for many years.  For the past several years I rented it out, and now it's empty and I'm trying to sell it. I don't know when the switch quit working.  I just discovered it a few days ago.  I also discovered that the previous tenant had turned off the breaker to that circuit.  So, I don't know when or why this problem came up and I don't know if the tenant had been tinkering with it.

Comment: Describing the condition before the switch quit working is helpful in making a guess about the problem.  My answer below is still the best guess I can think of.

Comment: I agree.  I'm back at the house now and ran continuity checks on the red and black.  Red checks out, black does not.  I guess I'll pull the cans out of the ceiling and see if I can  find anything there.  If not, I'll just wire the white and red like single pole and let it go at that.

Comment: I found a loose wire nut on the black wires in the ceiling, in a junction box adjacent to the nearest can.  Tightened it up and now I have continuity on the black wire at the switches.  But, I'm now back to where I was years ago, with both switches working independently like single pole switches.  Both turn the lights on and off, but it's not 3 way.

Comment: Post photos of the wiring in all three boxes then

Comment: Ok, I wasn't able to get a picture of the junction box.  Space is too confined.  But I've drawn it out - picture above.  I can see now why it doesn't work.  Red does nothing.  Both switch boxes are the same, and switches wired the same.

Comment: Was hoping for a comment or opinion on how this thing is wired.  Guess we're finished with it.  I'll button it back up and use it like two single pole switches.  Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an educated guess.....

[image]

Comment: I have not drawn a Carter 3-way.  The hot in this schematic is never connected to the lamp unless the lamp is illuminated (unlike in a Carter).  The top is an atypical schematic for the usual traveler system.  The bottom two are an incorrect attempt at making the top one.

Comment: you are correct -- that is a very odd drawing indeed, which tripped me up.